# Security for Hospital IT

Tags: encryption, network, java

I'm developing a program in Java intended to be utilized in a hospital. The system uses RMI internally between workstations and the server program. The program would be installed on the hospital's workstations and a hospital server. The server also listens to a socket and will authenticate with an RSA encryption scheme and retrieve queries to a SQL database. These transmissions are JSON.

I'm looking for a reasonably-secure method to communicate behind the hospital's firewall to user devices such as smartphones. Is there a best practice for doing this specific to a hospital setting (for example opening a port)?

Comment: TLS with certificate pinning?

Comment: I believe that shouldn't be possible from security perspective. The actual infrastructure of the hospitals IT should not interact with smartphone or BYOD in general. Even if we are not talking about a network that contains medical devices. If you are working with a hospital, ask their IT about it. If they are ok with it, they should be able to let your application (and only your application) communicate on a certain port.

Comment: I don't work in a hospital per-se, but in the past I've done tech work in healthcare facilities dealing with lots of HIPAA-protected, highly sensitive patient information. Anyway, FWIW the first question that jumps to mind about your plans is about whether it would serve some really essential purpose to connect with user devices. Because doing so would considerably increase the risk of the data your application deals with being compromised vs. restricting access to wired, presumably hardened workstations.

Comment: Of course, that assumes that either (a) your application does in fact handle sensitive patient data, or (b) could be used by a successful attacker to pivot and attack other systems that do actually handle patient data. But I'm inferring from your question that at less one and likely both of those things is probably true.

Comment: The phrase "authenticate with an RSA encryption" gives me cause for concern. Leaving aside the question of what devices are allowed to connect to your service, getting encryption *right* is difficult. Most of the vulnerabilities published in recent years are not faults in the algorithms but in the negotiation protocols that implement them. Don't invent your own - use TLS. And don't use an off the shelf implementation in your code, use the facilities provided by the platform. They are easier to keep up to date.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as being too subjective as `Would a hospital be interested in ...` is not something that we can likely answer.

Comment: "These transmissions are in JSON," assuming you are serializing the results, you could be in big trouble if you haven't [updated your apache commons](https://blogs.apache.org/foundation/entry/apache_commons_statement_to_widespread).

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your useful comments. Yes, this plan would involve Protected Health Information. I will proceed using sockets. Once I have a working system, I plan to run it by the local hospital's IT department. I'll answer the question with the information I learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use TLS to transmit securely over the network. If the data is indeed JSON, then it makes the most sense for the server to simply be a webserver and you would use TLS in the form of HTTPS to secure the communication.

For authentication, don't roll your own RSA based system.  TLS automatically gives you server authentication.   If you need client authentication as well, what you choose will depend on the application's needs.  If device based client auth is needed, client certs would be one way to handle this.

Additionally, don't wait until you've built the system to talk the the hospital's IT security staff.   You should talk to them as soon as you're finished with your intended design, at the latest.